# Hide info window shown via ClusterManager google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem that drive me crazy. I have implemented a map with a bunch of points using cluster manager and my manager setup is the follow:

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<myPOI>(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), getMap());
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new myPOIRenderer());
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterInfoWindowClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);

mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

and I add the markers with the addItem() method. Overriding the onClusterItemInfoWindowClick method I can easily check when a user tap on info window. The problem is that my method (see below) doesn't provide me the marker, but only the data object connected with it, so my question is: how can I programmatically close the info window inside that method?

```
@Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(myPOI item) {
        System.out.println("onClusterItemInfoWindowClick");
    }
```

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First override the `DefaultClusterRenderer<myPOI>`.

Then set your renderer on the cluster manager like this:

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(myClusterRenderer);
```

Then you can get the marker and hide it like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(final myPOI item) {
        myClusterRenderer.getMarker(item).hideInfoWindow();
  }
```

Comment: How could I use a similar approach to get all the markers (even the ones clustered)? Currently having trouble hiding all cluster items at once no mather the zoom. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better:

```
mClusterManager.getRenderer().setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyMarker>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<MyMarker> cluster) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```