# Disable infowindow when click cluster in mapV2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have referred this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering link to implement simple cluster in my application

Now I want to disable the cluster `onclick`

[image]

In my screen when I click 3 my info window is showing but I don't want to show infowindow; instead of that, I need to zoom the map.

I have tried

```
mClusterManager.onInfoWindowClick(null);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(null);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterInfoWindowClickListener(null);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(null);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(null);

        // render.setMarkersToCluster(false);
        render.setOnClusterClickListener(null);
        render.setOnClusterInfoWindowClickListener(null);
        render.setOnClusterItemClickListener(null);
        render.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(null);
```

These tries are not at all working; please give me some idea of what to do.

Comment: Have you tried `hideInfoWindow()` such that `myClusterRenderer.getMarker(item).hideInfoWindow();` ? For more details please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29034326)

Comment: Hey Madhu where are you from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we discuss above:

You can use `hideInfoWindow()` method

Set Renderer from cluster manager as following:

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(myClusterRenderer);
```

Get the marker and hide it as following:

```
@Override
public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(final myPOI item) {
    myClusterRenderer.getMarker(item).hideInfoWindow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks now i have an idea to work in cluster info window